# SOAP-ERROR on Live server

Tags: php, soap-client

Good day all,

I have a problem I have code a soap client that checks if a user have a valid TV license when they purchase a set of TV in my website,

The program works fine on local host with no errors and it returns the results, When moved to the live server, it gives the following error:

> Error!"SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://secure4.tvlic.co.za/AccountEnquiryService_Test_1.0/AccountEnquiryService.svc?wsdl'
>   : failed to load external entity
>   \"https://secure4.tvlic.co.za/AccountEnquiryService_Test_1.0/AccountEnquiryService.svc?wsdl\"\n"

My code :

```
<?php
$wdsl    = "https://secure4.tvlic.co.za/AccountEnquiryService_Test_1.0/AccountEnquiryService.svc?wsdl";
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
            'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
        )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$soapClientOptions = array(
        'stream_context' => $context,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
    );
//Generate GUID
function getGUID()
{
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid')) {
        return com_create_guid();
    } else {
        mt_srand((double) microtime() * 10000);
        $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
        $hyphen = chr(45); // "-"
        $uuid   = chr(123) // "{"
            . substr($charid, 0, 8) . $hyphen . substr($charid, 8, 4) . $hyphen . substr($charid, 12, 4) . $hyphen . substr($charid, 16, 4) . $hyphen . substr($charid, 20, 12) . chr(125); // "}"
        return trim($uuid, '{}');
    }
}

$quid = getGUID();


$licencetype = isset($_POST['licencetype']) ? $_POST['licencetype'] : NULL;
switch ($licencetype) {

    case 'domestic':
        $holder_id = isset($_POST['holder_id']) ? $_POST['holder_id'] : NULL;
        try {
            $client = new SoapClient($wdsl, $soapClientOptions);
            $client->__setLocation('https://secure4.tvlic.co.za/AccountEnquiryService_1.0/AccountEnquiryService.svc');

            $arrParams = array(
                'request' => array(
                    'Header' => array(
                        'Rquid' => $quid,
                        'ApiKey' => '2c261e98-90ca-4f7d-90a0-1f5e91ebf416'
                    ),
                    'AccountIdentifier' => $holder_id,
                    'AccountIdentifierType' => 'SaidNumber'
                )
            );

            $account   = $client->GetAccount($arrParams);
            echo json_encode($account);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo "Error!";
            echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
            echo 'Last response: ' . $client->__getLastResponse();
        }
        break;

    case 'business':
        $tvlicencenumber = isset($_POST['tvlicence']) ? $_POST['tvlicence'] : NULL;
        try {
            $client = new SoapClient($wdsl, $soapClientOptions);
            $client->__setLocation('https://secure4.tvlic.co.za/AccountEnquiryService_1.0/AccountEnquiryService.svc');

            $arrParams = array(
                'request' => array(
                    'Header' => array(
                        'Rquid' => $quid,
                        'ApiKey' => '5957237e-101c-4ff2-8fdc-4bd6c9393a1d'
                    ),
                    'AccountIdentifier' => $tvlicencenumber,
                    'AccountIdentifierType' => 'AccountNumber'
                )
            );

            $account   = $client->GetAccount($arrParams);
            echo json_encode($account);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo "Error!";
            echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
            echo 'Last response: ' . $client->__getLastResponse();
        }
        break;

    case 'dealer':
        $tvlicencenumber = isset($_POST['tvlicence']) ? $_POST['tvlicence'] : NULL;
        try {
            $client = new SoapClient($wdsl, $soapClientOptions);
            $client->__setLocation('https://secure4.tvlic.co.za/AccountEnquiryService_1.0/AccountEnquiryService.svc');

            $arrParams = array(
                'request' => array(
                    'Header' => array(
                        'Rquid' => $quid,
                        'ApiKey' => '5957237e-101c-4ff2-8fdc-4bd6c9393a1d'
                    ),
                    'AccountIdentifier' => $tvlicencenumber,
                    'AccountIdentifierType' => 'AccountNumber'
                )
            );

            $account   = $client->GetAccount($arrParams);
            echo json_encode($account);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo "Error!";
            echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
            echo 'Last response: ' . $client->__getLastResponse();
        }
        break;

    default:

        echo json_encode('Please select licence type');
}
?>
```

Xampp uses :

php 5.6

Live server

PHP/5.6.33-0+deb8u1

Please help solve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that `https://secure4.tvlic.co.za/AccountEnquiryService_1.0/AccountEnquiryService.svc` is the right location for SOAP client? When I open it in a browser, it shows an error - **Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.** Even if that's because I don't initialize the SOAP client to open it, you still seem to mix test and live APIs, judging from your WSDL (BTW you named the wsdl variable $wdsl, I guess typo, but you use it consistently so that shouldn't be an issue) and SOAP addresses.

Compare:

`↓ SOAP address (not working, even with ?wsdl appended)
https://secure4.tvlic.co.za/AccountEnquiryService_1.0/AccountEnquiryService.svc
https://secure4.tvlic.co.za/AccountEnquiryService_Test_1.0/AccountEnquiryService.svc?wsdl
 ↑ WSDL address (working)`

Comment: I have used the below one the wsdl that is working but still get same error, but on localhost works